# Is there any other way to speed up my MySQL query speed?

Tags: mysql

I initially selected part of the `stock_hfq` table, and then filtered it with `ts_code`.

I used the intermediate table `stock_hfq_temp` to filter the `stock_hfq` data. The data queried out is about 2M rows. It takes `2min 1s` without `exists`, and `1min 5s` with `exists`.However, adding the time to write the temporary table `stock_hfq_temp` and the time to create the index `ts_code` of the temporary table, the total time `difference` is only 4s.

Is there any other way to speed up my query speed?

`ts_code` is unique in the stock_hfq_temp table.

The relevant sentences and results are as follows:

```
select * from stock_hfq t where t.trade_date>'20110302';
Wall time: 2min 12s

select ts_code from stock_hfq_temp b 
Wall time: 8 ms

select * from stock_hfq t where t.trade_date>'20110302' and exists (select 1 from stock_hfq_temp b where b.ts_code=t.ts_code);
Wall time: 1min 5s
```

The analysis of the database is as follows:

```
mysql> select count(1) from stock_hfq;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 11546271 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3 min 31.64 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from (select distinct ts_code from stock_hfq b) t;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|     4480 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.26 sec)


mysql> select count(1) from stock_hfq_temp;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|     1502 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.18 sec)
```

Both tables are indexed.

```
mysql> show index from stock_hfq;
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| stock_hfq |          1 | ts_code    |            1 | ts_code     | A         |       16782 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| stock_hfq |          1 | trade_date |            1 | trade_date  | A         |       94773 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from stock_hfq_temp;
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| stock_hfq_temp |          1 | ts_code  |            1 | ts_code     | A         |        1502 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

explain:

```
mysql> explain select * from stock_hfq t where exists (select 1 from stock_hfq_temp b where b.ts_code =t.ts_code);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | filtered | Extra                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | index | ts_code       | ts_code | 83      | NULL                 | 1502 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; LooseScan |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | NULL       | ref   | ts_code       | ts_code | 83      | quant_test.b.ts_code |  681 |   100.00 | NULL                                |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1276 | Field or reference 'quant_test.t.ts_code' of SELECT #2 was resolved in SELECT #1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `quant_test`.`t`.`ts_code` AS `ts_code`,`quant_test`.`t`.`trade_date` AS `trade_date`,`quant_test`.`t`.`open` AS `open`,`quant_test`.`t`.`high` AS `high`,`quant_test`.`t`.`low` AS `low`,`quant_test`.`t`.`close` AS `close`,`quant_test`.`t`.`pre_close` AS `pre_close`,`quant_test`.`t`.`change` AS `change`,`quant_test`.`t`.`pct_chg` AS `pct_chg`,`quant_test`.`t`.`vol` AS `vol`,`quant_test`.`t`.`amount` AS `amount`,`quant_test`.`t`.`adj_factor` AS `adj_factor` from `quant_test`.`stock_hfq` `t` semi join (`quant_test`.`stock_hfq_temp` `b`) where (`quant_test`.`t`.`ts_code` = `quant_test`.`b`.`ts_code`) |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables :

```
/*
 Navicat Premium Data Transfer

 Source Server         : localhost_3306
 Source Server Type    : MySQL
 Source Server Version : 80021
 Source Host           : localhost:3306
 Source Schema         : quant_test

 Target Server Type    : MySQL
 Target Server Version : 80021
 File Encoding         : 65001

 Date: 12/06/2021 13:55:28
*/

SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for stock_hfq
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stock_hfq`;
CREATE TABLE `stock_hfq`  (
  `ts_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `trade_date` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `change` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `pct_chg` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `vol` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `adj_factor` double DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `ts_code`(`ts_code`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `trade_date`(`trade_date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

```
/*
 Navicat Premium Data Transfer

 Source Server         : localhost_3306
 Source Server Type    : MySQL
 Source Server Version : 80021
 Source Host           : localhost:3306
 Source Schema         : quant_test

 Target Server Type    : MySQL
 Target Server Version : 80021
 File Encoding         : 65001

 Date: 12/06/2021 13:55:38
*/

SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for stock_hfq_temp
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stock_hfq_temp`;
CREATE TABLE `stock_hfq_temp`  (
  `ts_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `trade_date` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `vol` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `h1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `mid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `l1` double DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `ts_code`(`ts_code`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables might be useful.

Comment: What is `stock_daily` and how does that query relate to the rest?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. At your prompt, I found that my SQL was written incorrectly. Is there room for improvement in query speed?

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN ` before your select statements. Read the output. MySQL will „explain“ where you could improve your select statements

Comment: @caramba See the Explain section posted. I